# Keep bouncing between errors, can't find good fix for Spinner/Adapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-spinner

I can't seem to figure out this `SimpleCursorAdapter`, every time I fix one error, another one pops up and if I follow the steps to fix that one, the first one comes up again. I feel like I'm going in circles here, so here's the chunk of code I'm trying to debug, note, the first part is just creating the DB, but I figured anything could be helpful in figuring it out.

```
        SQLiteDatabase rpgDB = null;
        String classFields = " (classID, className, classHP)";

        try {
            rpgDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("RpgDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            rpgDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + classTable);

            rpgDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + classTable + " (classID INT(3), className TEXT, classHP INT(4));");
            rpgDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + classTable + classFields + " VALUES (1, 'Warrior', 10);");
            rpgDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + classTable + classFields + " VALUES (2, 'Rogue', 7);");
            rpgDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + classTable + classFields + " VALUES (3, 'Mage', 5);");


            String query = "SELECT className AS _id FROM " + classTable;
            Cursor cursor = rpgDB.rawQuery(query, null);
            rpgDB.close();

            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.classDropDown };
            String[] spinnerFields = new String[] { "_id" };
            /**
             * Test code to check value of cursor
             */ 
            int count = cursor.getCount();
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) 
            {
                String test  = cursor.getString(0);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main, cursor, spinnerFields, to);
            int cursorcount = cursorAdapter.getCount();
            // cursorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            Spinner classDropDown = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.classDropDown);
            classDropDown.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }
```

Populating a Spinner from a SimpleCursorAdapter seems to be ridiculously troublesome.

**EDIT:** The error with this code is

```
Invalid statement in fill window
```

If I comment out the rpgDB.close() line

```
Spinner is not a view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter
```

If I change the select statement and spinnerfields to (with the DB commented out):

```
String query = "SELECT className FROM " + classTable;
String[] spinnerFields = new String[] { "className" };
```

I get:

```
column '_id' does not exist
```

**EDIT XML:** Here is the main.xml (also id main) XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="11pt"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textColor="@color/baseTextColor" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/classDropDown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**EXPLANATION:** So if anyone comes upon this in the future, thanks to Luksprog, I understand this a bit better (and he showed me the fixes):

The android.R.id and android.R.layout "ids/layouts" are default xml layouts for Android components such as a TextField and Spinner "list" layouts. The Spinner object is basically NOT complete on its own. You need another XML portion to define how the list itself looks and another one for the lines (the text1 is a default android TextField).

So in short, assign your "to" field to a TextField or use one of the default Android ones such as android.id.text1, but in order to use that I believe you also have to use the layout that CONTAINS the default android field, andoid.R.layout (in my case, simple_spinner_item). Lastly, set the dropdownresource to your own xml or an android default (mine was android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item).

Comment: Whats the error? Can you post your logcat?

Comment: Added the errors I'm getting right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
String query = "SELECT _id, className FROM " + classTable;
Cursor cursor = rpgDB.rawQuery(query, null);
int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
String[] spinnerFields = new String[] { "className"};
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner, cursor, spinnerFields, to);
cursorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinner classDropDown = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.classDropDown);
classDropDown.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

> Invalid statement in fill window

You can't close the database connection if you want to pull data from that `Cursor`.

> Spinner is not a view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter

The `to` int array represents the ids of the `Views` from the row layout file that you pass to the `SimpleCursorAdapter` to bind data from the `from` array (`R.layout.main`, I hope that you do have a layout file and just pass the activity's layout). The id `R.id.classDropDown` that you used there represents a `Spinner` view and a `SimpleCursorAdapter` doesn't know how to bind data to that(it can bind data to a `TextView` or `ImageView`). If you want a `Spinner` on each row(do you really want this? or do you want the default spinner row layout?) then use a custom adapter or a `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`.

> column '_id' does not exist

Because you don't have a column with this name in the table `classTable`. This column should be declared like:

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

Maybe you can check [this simple tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) for `Spinners`.

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought A SimpleCursorAdapter could bind to a Spinner since the line in the tutorial was "spinner.setAdapter(adapter)". I've switched my "to" to "android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item" and uncommented this line "cursorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);" after the other misc above fixes and I'm ALMOST there. I have a last problem of dropdowns within dropdowns instead of the text, so I think I just have to use the correct spinner item now. You wouldn't happen to know which one would you?

Comment: @Organiccat I've edited my answer. See if that solves the problems.

Comment: Indeed, that was it! I just figured out which ones to use too :)

If anyone is checking this, I'll mark the explanation above as well, thanks for the help!